# Keep the value of variable when open modal

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have a table where in each row I pass some variables through a foreach.

[image]

And when I click 'Delete' it opens a modal, which has the first value of the table, does not matter if I click the delete button in the row with ID 5, which will get the value of ID 1.

The code is this:

```
<tbody>
     @foreach ($admins as $key => $admin)
      <tr>
        <td class="idadmin tdcenter"><p id="margindata" class="tdmenuadmin">{{$admin->id}}</p></td>
        <td class="nameadmin"><p id="margindata" class="tdmenuadmin">{{$admin->name}}</p></td>
        <td class="emailadmin"><p id="margindata" class="tdmenuadmin">{{$admin->email}}</p></td>
        <td class="actionsadmin tdmenuadmin">

         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deletemenuadmin" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formdeleteadmin" id="margindata">Delete</button>

         <div id="formdeleteadmin" class="modal fade" role="dialog"> <!-- DIV TO SHOW THE CREATE PROJECT FORM 1 START HERE-->

         <div class="modal-dialog" style="background-color:#23517F;">

         <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:#23517F;">

            <div class="modal-header">

            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

            <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:black;">{{$admin->id}}¿Estas seguro de borrar al administrador?</h4>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <a href="{{ route('admin.admins') }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">No</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.admins.destroy',$admin->id)}}">
                        <input type="submit" value="Si" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
                        {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="closemodal">Close</button>

            </div>

         </div>

       </div>

     </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

When I click the Delete it shows me this modal: (it is trimmed)

[image]

And if I click yes it goes to the path that indicates the code and executes the function of the controller, the function is this:

```
public function destroyAdmin($id) //Eliminar la informacion de un admin
    {
        $admin = Admin::find($id);
        $admin->delete();
        Session::flash('success','El admin ha sido eliminado con éxito.');
        return redirect()->route('admin.admins');
    }
```

How can I do that when I open the modal, I keep the ID of the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for all delete button your data-target is same.that's why always open the first model.use different name for all data-target.u can create dynamic data-target by adding primary key with the data-target 
edited code is below

```
<tbody>
 @foreach ($admins as $key => $admin)
  <tr>
    <td class="idadmin tdcenter"><p id="margindata" class="tdmenuadmin">{{$admin->id}}</p></td>
    <td class="nameadmin"><p id="margindata" class="tdmenuadmin">{{$admin->name}}</p></td>
    <td class="emailadmin"><p id="margindata" class="tdmenuadmin">{{$admin->email}}</p></td>
    <td class="actionsadmin tdmenuadmin">

     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deletemenuadmin" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formdeleteadmin{{$admin->id}}" id="margindata">Delete</button>

    <div id="formdeleteadmin{{$admin->id}}" class="modal fade" role="dialog"> <!-- DIV TO SHOW THE CREATE PROJECT FORM 1 START HERE-->

     <div class="modal-dialog" style="background-color:#23517F;">

     <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:#23517F;">

        <div class="modal-header">

        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

        <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:black;">{{$admin->id}}¿Estas seguro de borrar al administrador?</h4>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <a href="{{ route('admin.admins') }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">No</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.admins.destroy',$admin->id)}}">
                    <input type="submit" value="Si" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
                    {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="closemodal">Close</button>

        </div>

     </div>

   </div>

 </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Create just one modal outside the table and populate the fields using javascript and the event that opens the modal.

Your HTML will be cleaner and it will work as expected.

You can use attributes on button like

```
<button type="button" 
    class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deletemenuadmin" 
    data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target="#formdeleteadmin"
    data-url="{{ route('admin.admins.destroy',$admin->id) }}" 
    data-username="{{ $admin->name }}" 
    data-userid="{{ $admin->id}}">
    Delete
</button>
```